# Formatting resumes heading

Tags: cv

I am working on changing my resume with latex. I found an existing format online so I decided to use that to modify my resume. I wanted to represent something but I am having hard time figuring out how to do that.. Below is how I wanted to represent it:

[image]

and this is how it is coming:

[image]

As you can see above, I don't want `Mumbai, India` and `Bachelors of Technology in Chemical Engineering` and `Aug. 2011 – Apr. 2015` so if I remove these things then it gets messed up totally. Below is my `test.tex` format:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=0.40in, right=0.40in, top=0.25in, bottom=0.15in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\hyphenation{Some-long-word}

\usepackage{resume}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \textbf{\LARGE Hello World}\\[0.5ex]
    \textscale{1.05}{Some Address, Apt \#123, Abc Pqr, SA-92112\\
        \Letter\hspace{0.1ex} \href{mailto:abc@gmail.com}{abc@gmail.com}
        \hfill
        \Mobilefone\hspace{0.1ex} +1 (111) 111-1111}
\end{center}
\spacedhrule{-1.0ex}{-0.5ex}

\roottitle{OPERATIONS/GENERAL MANAGEMENT EXECUTIVE}

\headedsection
{High-Volume Operations | Supply Chain Management | Organization Development | Operational Leadership}
{Mumbai, India}
{Bachelors of Technology in Chemical Engineering}
{\period{Aug}{2011}{Apr}{2015}}
{Creates business process improvement, utilizing entrepreneurial vision, technological understanding, and exceptional relationship management fostering revenue growth, cost savings, and improved productivity\\
Versatile leader repeatedly recruited to turn around "broken" operations, launch new facilities and services, and integrate merged staff and operations. Strategic thinker with equal emphasis on tactical execution and common sense problem solving to deliver financial results, operational improvements, production and service enhancements. Calm and focused in high-pressure situations; able to develop/challenge employees toward growth and goal attainment.}

\spacedhrule{0.8ex}{0.0ex}

\roottitle{TRAINING AND WORKSHOPS}
\begin{circlist}
    \item Participated in 3 days Conflict-Positive Workshop - workshop on managing a conflict with a positive attitude and perspective.
    \item Participated in MBTI workshop - a psychometric tool to understand different personality type.
\end{circlist}

\spacedhrule{0.8ex}{0.0ex}

\roottitle{SKILLS \& OTHERS}
\begin{indentsection}
    \skill{Computer}{SQL, Python, Excel}
    \skill{Interests}{Strategy Games, Music, Adventure Sports}
\end{indentsection}

\end{document}
```

And below is the `resume.sty` format which is being used to generate the resume.

```
\usepackage{footmisc,marvosym}

% Setup the hyperrefs with the right color.
\usepackage{url,hyperref,xcolor}
\definecolor{BerkeleyBlue}{HTML}{003262}
\hypersetup{colorlinks, linkcolor={BerkeleyBlue}, citecolor={BerkeleyBlue}, urlcolor={BerkeleyBlue}}


%%% LOAD AND SETUP PACKAGES

% To finetune lists with a inline heading and indented content.
% See the Experiences section in the example.
\usepackage{enumitem}

% For multiple column text.
\usepackage{multicol}

% For \textscale, which I prefer over \sc (small caps).
% See the \acr command definition below.
\usepackage{relsize}

% XeTeX specific stuff with fall-back.
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex

\usepackage{fontspec}

% the main font, with all features on
\setmainfont
[ ExternalLocation ,
Mapping          = tex-text ,
Numbers          = OldStyle ,
Ligatures        = {Common,Contextual} ,
BoldFont         = texgyrepagella-bold.otf ,
ItalicFont       = texgyrepagella-italic.otf ,
BoldItalicFont   = texgyrepagella-bolditalic.otf ]
{texgyrepagella-regular.otf}

% same like the main font, but without old-style nums
\newfontfamily\newnums
[ ExternalLocation ,
Mapping          = tex-text ,
Ligatures        = {Common,Contextual} ,
BoldFont         = texgyrepagella-bold.otf ,
ItalicFont       = texgyrepagella-italic.otf ,
BoldItalicFont   = texgyrepagella-bolditalic.otf ]
{texgyrepagella-regular.otf}
% Comment out the previous statement and uncomment the following line to use the
% Linux Libertine font (it has nice lignatures).
% Make sure to have the `ttf-linux-libertine` package installed on Ubuntu.
%  \setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Numbers=OldStyle, Ligatures={Common,Contextual}]{Linux Libertine O}

% needs an experimental and impossible to find package for xetex
\usepackage[protrusion]{microtype}

\else

% this case we likely use the `pdftex` back-end
% therefor we lack:
%  * lower case numbers,
%  * ligatures and
%  * some typographic niceties
% We do make use of the possibility to use `microtype`
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage[expansion,protrusion]{microtype}

\fi


%%% DOCUMENT WIDE STYLING

\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0em}


%%% CUSTOM COMMANDS

% main title (name) with subtitle (date)
\newcommand\maintitle[3]{\vbox to 0pt{\hfill\scriptsize\color{gray} #3}\vspace{-0.4em}\noindent{\LARGE \textbf{#1}}\ \ \ \emph{#2}}

% title for the root sections (experience, education, etc) of the resume
\newcommand*\roottitle[1]{\vspace{-1ex}\subsection*{#1}\vspace{-0.5ex}\nopagebreak[4]}

% it seems not to work when simply using \parindent...
\newlength{\newparindent}
\addtolength{\newparindent}{\parindent}

% a double \parindent...
\newlength{\doubleparindent}
\addtolength{\doubleparindent}{2\parindent}

% indentsection style, used for sections that aren't already in lists
% that need indentation to the level of all text in the document
\newenvironment{indentsection}%
{\begin{list}{}%
    {   
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}
        \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
        \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
        \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
        \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}}
    }
{\end{list}}

\newenvironment{circlist}%
{\begin{list}{$\circ$}%
        {   
            \setlength{\leftmargin}{\newparindent}
            \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
            \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
            \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
            \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}}
    }
    {\end{list}}

\newcommand{\period}[4]{#1.\ #2 -- #3.\ #4}

% headerrow command, used for a new employer
\newcommand{\headedsection}[5]
{\nopagebreak[4]
    \begin{indentsection}
        \item[]\textscale{1.063}{\textbf{#1}}, \textsl{#2}\\
        \textsl{#3}\hfill\textsl{#4}\\
        {#5}
    \end{indentsection}
\nopagebreak[4]}

\newcommand{\headedsubsection}[3]
{\nopagebreak[4]
    \begin{indentsection}
        \item[]\textsl{#1}\hfill\textsl{#2}\\
        {#3}
    \end{indentsection}
    \nopagebreak[4]}

\newcommand{\headedsectiontwo}[4]
{\nopagebreak[4]
    \begin{indentsection}
        \item[]\textscale{1.063}{\textbf{#1}}\\
        \textsl{Guide:\ #3\hfill\textsl{#2}}\\
        {#4}
    \end{indentsection}
    \nopagebreak[4]}

\newcommand{\headedsectionfour}[5]
{\nopagebreak[5]
    \begin{indentsection}
        \item[]\textscale{1.063}{\textbf{#1}},  \textsl{#2}\\
        \textsl{Topic:\ #4\hfill\textsl{#3}}\\
        {#5}
    \end{indentsection}
    \nopagebreak[5]}


% \newcommand{\headedsection}[5]
% {\nopagebreak[4]
%   \begin{indentsection}
%       \item[]\textscale{1.063}{\textbf{#1}}, \textsl{#2}\\
%       \textsl{#3}\hfill\textsl{#4}\\
%       {#5}
%   \end{indentsection}
% \nopagebreak[4]}


\newcommand{\headedsectionthree}[4]
{\nopagebreak[4]
    \begin{indentsection}
        \item[]\textscale{1.063}{\textbf{#1}}\\
        \textsl{\ #3\hfill\textsl{#2}}\\
        {#4}
    \end{indentsection}
    \nopagebreak[4]}
\newcommand{\skill}[2]
{\item[] \textbf{#1}{:} #2}

\newcommand{\award}[4]
{\nopagebreak[4]
    \begin{indentsection}
        \item[] \textbf{#1} | \textsl{#2} \hfill \textsl{#3}\\
        #4
    \end{indentsection}
\nopagebreak[4]}

% \vspace variaties
\newcommand{\breakvspace}[1]{\pagebreak[2]\vspace{#1}\pagebreak[2]}
\newcommand{\nobreakvspace}[1]{\nopagebreak[4]\vspace{#1}\nopagebreak[4]}

% \spacedhrule a horizontal line with some vertical space before and after it
\newcommand{\spacedhrule}[2]{\breakvspace{#1}\hrule\nobreakvspace{#2}}
```

This is the [online template](https://www.overleaf.com/articles/abhinay-korukondas-resume/xpghvdncnvng) I am using to modify my resume. I think I need to add another section just for that portion but not sure how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome TSE.

You should delete the text without removing the {}, like below:

```
\headedsection
{High-Volume Operations | Supply Chain Management | Organization Development | Operational Leadership}
{}
{}
{}
{Creates business process improvement, utilizing entrepreneurial vision, technological understanding, and exceptional relationship management fostering revenue growth, cost savings, and improved productivity\\
Versatile leader repeatedly recruited to turn around "broken" operations, launch new facilities and services, and integrate merged staff and operations. Strategic thinker with equal emphasis on tactical execution and common sense problem solving to deliver financial results, operational improvements, production and service enhancements. Calm and focused in high-pressure situations; able to develop/challenge employees toward growth and goal attainment.}
```

I strongly suggest you to use the `moderncv` package. It provides you an exteremly beautiful resume. You can find many examples in the web.

## edit

based on the new comment:

Try the follwoing:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd\headedsection{,}{}{}{}
```

after

```
\usepackage{resume}
```

Comment: yeah this works fine.. Only issue is after `Leadership`, I see a comma `,`. I am not sure why. Is there any way we can get rid of comma after `Leadership`?

Comment: put the following code after `\usepackage{resume}`: `\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd\headedsection{,}{}{}{}`. You can also remove `,` from `resume.sty` but I perfere the first way which patch the style file.